# Intershop server in docker

Tags: linux, intershop

I'm trying to setup a local development environment on a linux machine. The ideal setup would be using a docker container spinning up the server with a shared directory to push code changes. 
The question is if this is an accepted approach to use? Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is

- a public guide how to setup an environment on ICM 7.9 , https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/28K663, and
- a sample linux VM on ICM 7.5.5. provided in case you have got a support login - https://support.intershop.com/static/Customer-Support-offers-a-Linux-VM-as-an-example--development-environment-for-Intershop-7.5.html

but both of them are not related to a docker container, however it may help you with settung up a development environment in there.